# how to stop javascript or jquery function within a javascript or jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to stop a function inside function but outside my stop function --scenario--
NumberOne() will do something and NumberTwo() will stop NumberOne() and do something

example

```
function NumberOne(){
   alert("hello");       
}

function NumberTwo(){
  NumberOne().stop();
  alert("it stopped");
 }
```

Comment: Nest the functions

Comment: You have to be more specific. A function will run through pretty quick,
so it doesn't make much sense to stop it. I would be better you give
your function a condition, so if that condition is true/false, the function
will act in a certain way.

Comment: i call make a noty in my first function so i want to make another noty in my second function but first want to clear my previous one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not clear of what you want to achieve but if you want to stop the JS from executing the script further use `return;`

Comment: Isn't that only for loops?

Comment: i call make a  noty in my first function so i want to make another  noty in my second function but first want to clear my previous one .

Comment: The return statement stops the execution of a function and returns a value from that function. In your case it will only escape or return from current scope. In loops we use break; to break out of loops or any condition statements